# Search Query misses out a particular item always

Tags: search, search-results, managed-property

The search always leaves out an item when searched with some other property value rather than the title.
When searched with title i get the result but not with any other property value.

Comment: Have you created Managed property to search by that  Property eg: 
<managed Property>:'Searchtext'

Comment: Yes,most other items when searched by the same property comes up.I tried to re-index the list also.Still for that particular item when searched by the property no results come up

Comment: After creating the managed property have you run the full crawl ?
If you run full Crawl it will retrieve the data on selected property for sure.